# What is the idiomatic way of dealing with return data from a conditionally asynchronous function?

Tags: asynchronous, go, goroutine

I have a function which may or may not be called as an asynchronous go-routine.

```
func APICall(request *HTTPRequest) *HTTPResponse
```

`*HTTPRequest` is a pointer to a struct which contains various pieces of data required in order to build a request:

```
type HTTPRequest struct {
    // Represents a request to the twitter API
    method string
    baseurl string
    urlParams map[string]string
    bodyParams map[string]string
    authParams map[string]string
    responseChan chan *HTTPResponse
}
```

If called as a goroutine, i.e a channel is passed in; we build the request and write the response into the *HTTPResponse object (also a struct) of the provided channel. What is the most graceful / idiomatic way to accept a call to the function without a channel (ie. Not async)

At the moment, we do something like this within the body of APICall to deal with both kinds of function call:

```
if request.responseChan != nil { // If a response channel has been specified, write to that channel
request.responseChan <- &twitterHTTPResponse{body, nil}
return nil // Not returning a struct
} else {
return &twitterHTTPResponse{body, nil} // Return a pointer to a new struct representing the response
}
```

Are we along the right lines?

Comment: The idiomatic approach is to write synchronous APIs and leave it to the caller to execute the call from a goroutine.

Comment: How does that resolve the ambiguity of whether or not a channel is required?

Comment: Synchronous APIs do not use channels.  The idiomatic approach is to remove `responeChan` from `HTTPRequest` and to simply return `&twitterHTTPResponse{body, nil}, err` from the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idiomatic approach is to provide a synchronous API:

```
type HTTPRequest struct {
    // Represents a request to the twitter API
    method string
    baseurl string
    urlParams map[string]string
    bodyParams map[string]string
    authParams map[string]string
}

func APICall(request *HTTPRequest) *HTTPResponse {
    ...
    return &twitterHTTPResponse{body, nil} 
}
```

The caller an can easily create a goroutine if it needs to run the call concurrently.  For example:

```
r := make(chan *HTTPResponse) 
go func() {
    r <- APICall(req)
}()

... do some other work

resp := <- r
```

Synchronous APIs are idiomatic for a couple of reasons:

- Synchronous APIs are easier to use and understand.
- Synchronous APIs don't make incorrect assumptions about how the application is managing concurrency.  For example, the application may want to use a wait group to wait for completion instead of receiving on a channel as assumed by the API.

Comment: Thanks Cerise. Is this idiomatic mainly because an API request normally involves use of the net/http stdlib which itself is highly async already?  (and so running it as a goroutine should theoretically provide little to no benefit if the API function is properly separate from other application logic?)

Comment: I updated the answer to describe why synchronous APIs are idiomatic.  The net/http client API is synchronous.